# How can I get the values of datastore, resource_pool, folder to pass for the placement parameter in the vmware.vmware_rest.vcenter_vm: module

Tags: ansible

I tried to use `vmware.vmware_rest.vcenter_vm` module in Ansible to clone an exiting vm from the vCenter. Here is the piece of that module I used for the cloning task. I am unclear what values I should pass to the placement parameter and how to get them in this module for the clone task.

I tried the below way

```yaml
 - name: Gather source VM info of {{ vm_guest_name }}
       community.vmware.vmware_vm_info:
         hostname: '{{ vcenter_host }}'
         username: '{{ vcenter_user }}'
         password: '{{ vcenter_password }}'
         vm_name: "{{ vm_guest_name }}"
       delegate_to: localhost
       register: vm_info
       
     - name: Printing  info of datastore in {{ vm_guest_name }}
       debug:
         var: vm_info.virtual_machines[0].datastore_url[0].name

     - name: Printing  info of folder in {{ vm_guest_name }}
       debug:
         var: vm_info.virtual_machines[0].folder
     
     - name: Printing info of resource_pool in {{ vm_guest_name }}
       debug:
         var: vm_info.virtual_machines[0].resource_pool


     - name: Cloning the {{ vm_guest_name }} (source VM)
       vmware.vmware_rest.vcenter_vm:
         placement:
           datastore: "{{ lookup('vmware.vmware_rest.datastore_moid', vm_info.virtual_machines[0].datastore_url[0].name) }}"
           folder: "{{ lookup('vmware.vmware_rest.folder_moid', vm_info.virtual_machines[0].folder) }}"
           resource_pool: "{{ lookup('vmware.vmware_rest.resource_pool_moid', vm_info.virtual_machines[0].resource_pool) }}"
         vcenter_hostname: "{{ vcenter_host }}"
         vcenter_username: "{{ vcenter_user }}"
         vcenter_password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
         source: "{{ vm_info.virtual_machines[0].moid }}"
         name: "{{ vm_cloned_name }}"
         state: clone
         
       register: clone_results

     - debug:
        var: clone_results
```

I get the below errors

```
"messages": [
      {
        "args": [
          "object:  privileges: VirtualMachine.Inventory.CreateFromExisting,object:  privileges: Resource.AssignVMToPool"
        ],
        "default_message": "The following (object:  privileges: VirtualMachine.Inventory.CreateFromExisting,object:  privileges: Resource.AssignVMToPool) privileges are insufficient to user",
        "id": "vapi.authz.error.no.privs"
      }
    ]

"placement": {
        "datastore": "",
        "folder": "",
        "resource_pool": ""
      }
```

Comment: According the error message `The following (object:  privileges: VirtualMachine.Inventory.CreateFromExisting,object:  privileges: Resource.AssignVMToPool) privileges are insufficient to user` you will need to grant the privileges in vCenter to the user used.

Comment: We tried Didnt'work .